# Openstack HeatClient api to query heat output-show

Tags: rest, openstack, openstack-heat

How to fetch output data using Heat Rest Api.

For eg.

```
heat output-show <stack-name> <keyword-name>
```

I want to fetch this using rest api..

Comment: Did you have a look at the REST API documentation at all? http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-orchestration-v1.html

Comment: yes thanks, i have already gone through this document but this requires some experience over heatclient to understand.

Answer (score 0):

somehow i manage to query this using rest api-

```
ks_client = Keystone_Client(**cred)
heat_endpoint = ks_client.service_catalog.url_for(service_type='orchestration', endpoint_type='publicURL')
heatclient = Heat_Client('1', heat_endpoint, token=ks_client.auth_token)
output = heatclient.stacks.get(stack_id='08615c01-86cc-4843-acec-d43126081241')
```

Now **output** is the metadata of my stack which is of dictionary type.
To get the output value of the stack.

```
print(output[0]['output_value'])
```